# Whats the difference between Azure Cosmos DB and Azure Spatial Anchors?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-spatial-anchors

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between the Spatial Anchors Account and the Azure Cosmos DB. Are both needed for persistent anchors? Or is the Cosmos DB only relevant for cross-platform apps?

I guess a different way to ask my question would be: can you use spatial anchors without a Cosmos DB and if yes, how are spatial anchors stored on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Spatial Anchors without a Cosmos DB. The spatial anchors themselves are stored within the Azure Spatial Anchors service, but to later query for a spatial anchor stored in the service you need the [Identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.spatialanchors.cloudspatialanchor.identifier#Microsoft_Azure_SpatialAnchors_CloudSpatialAnchor_Identifier) of that anchor.

At the moment the Azure Spatial Anchor service does have a way to "give me all identifiers for all anchors you have stored". You can only ask for anchors by identifiers. So if you save a spatial anchor and don't separately save the identifier yourself, you won't be able to retrieve the anchor later and it is basically lost.

That is why you need something to save the identifiers. In the examples Microsoft uses Cosmos DB, but you can use several other ways of storing the identifiers e.g. other databases, files, etc.

Comment: I tweaked the phrasing a bit in the second paragraph. The anchor ids are stored in the Azure Spatial Anchors service, but there is currently no way to enumerate them. It may also be worth mentioning that [Coarse relocalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/concepts/coarse-reloc?tabs=csharp) can be used to find anchors near the device without having any initial ids.

Comment: There's a suggestion already around [showing a list of all the created anchors in a webpage](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919252-azure-spatial-anchors/suggestions/37107037-show-a-list-of-all-the-created-anchors-in-a-webpag). If you think that something like this would be useful, upvote it, add comments describing how you'd make use of such a feature, or open new items on that site. This information helps us prioritize feature work.